# SQL INSERT with no errors

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem where I get no errors nothing it all goes though as if nothing was wrong! I had all this working then all of a sudden it just stopped working. All my other SQL stuff works on my script apart from this:

```
// Submit the form and enter the details into the database
    $result = $dbc->prepare('INSERT INTO users (user_name, pwd, date, user_level) values(?,?,?,?)');
    $result->bind_param('sssi', $username, $hash, $now, $userlevel);
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $result->error);
    $result->execute();
    $result->close();
```

It returns no errors nothing. Its very strange. Nothing is inserted into the DB.

Comment: Try outputting the error after `execute` as well. One thing that stands out is that `date` is a reserved word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe first execute, then check the error message?

```
    $result = $dbc->prepare('INSERT INTO users (user_name, pwd, date, user_level) values(?,?,?,?)');
    $result->bind_param('sssi', $username, $hash, $now, $userlevel);
    $result->execute();
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $result->error);
    $result->close();
```

Comment: That got it! was due to me forgetting to remove a unused column in the DB. It threw the error (After putting the error script in the right place!) thanks :)